# How to pass the UIView with a gesture recognizer as parameter?

Tags: ios, swift, arguments, selector, uigesturerecognizer

I use:

```
  tap.addTarget(self, action: "handleTap:")
  self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

I want to access to the `view.tag` property of `view` in `handleTap` method.
So how do I pass the UIView which "tap" is in as parameter of handleTap?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
func handleTap(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if let tag = sender.view?.tag {
        println(tag)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following code.

```
 override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true
        var tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleTap:"))
        self.view.tag = 101
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }

    func handleTap(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if let tag = sender.view?.tag {
            println(tag)
        }
    }
```